# How to correctly display OpenCv Portrait mode in Full screen?

Tags: python, linux, opencv, webcam, landscape-portrait

I am trying to corectly show **Landscape** and **Portrait** mode with OpenCv in Python.

I am using a small ****2.8" TFT screen**** with a resolution of *240 x 320* attached to a micro computer that is running ****Debian buster****.
The webcam I am using has the following supported resolutions:

```
640x480 352x288 320x240 176x144 160x120
```

With the **cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN** the screen starts with grey edges at top and bottom.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1)  
cv2.namedWindow('default', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)  
cv2.setWindowProperty('default', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,
                      cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)  

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    if viewMode == "normal": 
        cv2.imshow("default", frame)
```

Then I rotate it with **cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE** to get the **Landscape** mode.

```
    elif viewMode == "landscape": 
        frame = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE) 
        cv2.imshow("default", frame)
```

It works fine with proper scaling without stretching in both X and Y axes.

To get the **Portrait** mode in full screen, I use **cv2.WINDOW_FREERATIO**. But it streches in Y axis and the display is not good.

```
    elif viewMode == "portrait": 
        cv2.namedWindow('freeratio', cv2.WINDOW_FREERATIO)
        cv2.setWindowProperty(
            'freeratio', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
        cv2.imshow("freeratio", frame)
```

What is the correct way to show **Portrait** mode in this case without streching and maintaining proper scaling in both axes?

Here's my full code below:

```
import cv2 

# viewMode = "normal"  
# viewMode = "landscape"  
viewMode = "portrait" 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1)  
cv2.namedWindow('default', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)  
cv2.setWindowProperty('default', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,
                      cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)  

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    if viewMode == "normal": 
        cv2.imshow("default", frame)
    elif viewMode == "landscape": 
        frame = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE) 
        cv2.imshow("default", frame)
    elif viewMode == "portrait": 
        cv2.namedWindow('freeratio', cv2.WINDOW_FREERATIO)
        cv2.setWindowProperty(
            'freeratio', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
        cv2.imshow("freeratio", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

cap.release()
```

****Note:**** I have tried most suggestions I found on other similar posts/threads but to no avail. Resizing/cropping or manually setting the resolution does not help. It either gives me the greyed borders on topand bottom or streched out. Could it be any setting in the webcam/Debian that's causing the issue?

Any help/suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: the correct way is to do your own GUI. OpenCV's imshow does not support "letterboxing". either the image is stretched to fit the window, or the window is sized to fit the picture, or the window is fullscreen and the picture is put in the top left corner at 1:1 scale. -- if you think there ought to be letterboxing, feel free to open an issue. there might even be one already, but nobody's bothered enough to implement the functionality and submit a pull request

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will look into OpenCV letterboxing.